# How to add toolbar to bottom, top, left, or right of the inside of a listbox in WPF?

Tags: wpf, listbox, toolbar, listboxitem

I have a listbox with a style that has rounded corners.  I'd like to add a toolbar inside the listbox that pertains to that specific list box.  Currently, if I add a toolbar inside the grid that contains a listbox, it will overlap the last item in the row (depending on the height of the toolbar).  Does anyone have any ideas on the best way to implement this?  I know I could create a border control that matches the look of the listbox edges and then place a listbox that has a style without borders inside the main border stacked with the toolbar at the bottom, but I'm hoping there is a better way to keep my current listbox style and just place a toolbar inside the bottom of the listbox that doesn't hide any listbox items.

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I follow entirely, but I think you have a couple of options:

1. Integrate the `ToolBar` into the `ListBox` template, probably by writing a control that extends `ListBox` and adds a property to set the `ToolBar` items.
2. Turn off the `Border` on the `ListBox` and stick your own `Border` around it that also encompasses the `ToolBar`.

2 is a little easier and is probably what you want.

**Example of 1**

(I didn't bother subclassing ListBox here - I just hard-coded some ToolBar items instead)

```
    <Grid Margin="10">
        <ListBox>
            <ListBox.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                    <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}" Padding="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}" Name="Bd" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" CornerRadius="5">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <ToolBarTray Background="White">
                                <ToolBar Band="1" BandIndex="1">
                                    <Button>
                                        Cut
                                    </Button>
                                    <Button>
                                        Copy
                                    </Button>
                                    <Button>
                                        Paste
                                    </Button>
                                </ToolBar>
                                <ToolBar Band="2" BandIndex="1">
                                    <Button>
                                        Undo
                                    </Button>
                                    <Button>
                                        Redo
                                    </Button>
                                </ToolBar>
                            </ToolBarTray>
                            <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}" Focusable="False">
                                <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="Bd">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <DynamicResource ResourceKey="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.IsGrouping" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="False"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ListBox.Template>
            <ListBoxItem>One</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Two</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Three</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

**Example of 2**

```
<Grid Margin="10">
    <Border CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Padding="1">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <ToolBarTray Background="White">
                <ToolBar Band="1" BandIndex="1">
                    <Button>
                        Cut
                    </Button>
                    <Button>
                        Copy
                    </Button>
                    <Button>
                        Paste
                    </Button>
                </ToolBar>
                <ToolBar Band="2" BandIndex="1">
                    <Button>
                        Undo
                    </Button>
                    <Button>
                        Redo
                    </Button>
                </ToolBar>
            </ToolBarTray>
            <ListBox Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="0">
                <ListBoxItem>One</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Two</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Three</ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

In both cases, the result looks similar:

[alt text http://img42.imageshack.us/img42/372/screenshotof.png](http://img42.imageshack.us/img42/372/screenshotof.png)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have something declared wrong in your code if things are being overlapped visually. You should have your ListBox declared with Grid.Row="0" and your toolbar as Grid.Row="1" (or something similar) if you'd like them not to overlap. [This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745058.aspx) explains grid layouts well.

If your ListBoxItems are not databound, you can just add a ListBoxItem with a custom style as the last item in your list. Otherwise you can use a [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx) to format your item styles based on the content bound within.